# How to prevent toplevel window (splash screen) freezing while executing a function?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, splash-screen

I'm trying to display a splash screen while executing a function but it's not working. The progress bar freezes alongside with the toplevel window. I've also tried out `threading.Thread` but couldn't make it work either. How can I achieve this?

Here's a simple reproducible example I've created for this situation:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def loading_window():

    toplevel_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    toplevel_window.overrideredirect(1)

    label = tk.Label(toplevel_window, text='Please wait')
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(toplevel_window, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode="indeterminate")
    progressbar.start()
    progressbar.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def update_splash_screen():

        progressbar.update()

        if is_process_over.get():
            toplevel_window.destroy()
            return

        toplevel_window.after(200, update_splash_screen)

    if is_process_over.get():

        toplevel_window.destroy()
        return

    toplevel_window.after(200, update_splash_screen)
    toplevel_window.grab_set()

def func1():

    root.after(100, func2)
    loading_window()

def func2():

    for _ in range(250000000):
        pass

    is_process_over.set(True)
    label.configure(text="DONE")
    root.update_idletasks()

root = tk.Tk()
is_process_over = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Button", command=func1)
btn.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

label = tk.Label(root, text="Label")
label.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How did you try to use threads?

Comment: @Alexander Actually, I was trying for customtkinter module, it's not working there for some reason. I thought it had something to do with tkinter but apparently it's customtkinter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with threads.  Inside of your `func1` function you can simply swap out the line `root.after(100, func2)` with a call that starts a thread for `func2`.  However in more complicated examples you should always make sure that the code that is operating in the separate thread does not interact with the gui.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

def loading_window():

    toplevel_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    toplevel_window.overrideredirect(1)

    label = tk.Label(toplevel_window, text='Please wait')
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(toplevel_window, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode="indeterminate")
    progressbar.start()
    progressbar.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def update_splash_screen():

        progressbar.update()

        if is_process_over.get():
            toplevel_window.destroy()
            return

        toplevel_window.after(200, update_splash_screen)

    if is_process_over.get():

        toplevel_window.destroy()
        return

    toplevel_window.after(200, update_splash_screen)
    toplevel_window.grab_set()

def func1():
    mythread = threading.Thread(target=func2)
    mythread.start()
    loading_window()

def func2():
    for _ in range(250000000):
        pass
    is_process_over.set(True)
    label.configure(text="DONE")
    root.update_idletasks()

root = tk.Tk()
is_process_over = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Button", command=func1)
btn.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

label = tk.Label(root, text="Label")
label.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

root.mainloop()

pythonmultithreading
```

Comment: line 36, in func1
    mythread = threading.thread(target=func2)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'thread'. Did you mean: 'Thread'?

Comment: Should be like this  `mythread = threading.Thread(target=func2)` Worked fine for mow.

Comment: @toyotaSupra  Yes I had a typo in answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Unlike the other answers to similar questions, this answer 1) does not create two instances of Tk, 2) does not use a timer to supposedly take the place of time-consuming work, 3) does use a progress bar, and 4) does actually work.